# Best practices to develop VueJS app with Webpack, SASS, NPM ...?

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js

I am writing application by using Python/Flask as the API back-end, and want to separate the front-end (browser-based) as an individual project (VueJS). I've read about Webpack, but I can't find any best practice to start, such as: can we use NPM to manage dependencies, use webpack for front-end not using an Node app as an entry ...

Thanks alot

Comment: If you want to build the frontend in vue you should absolutely use the vue cli to set it up. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli. From there you can dig into what their presets are doing with webpack and tweak it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I gonna take a look

Answer (score 1):

WebPack isn't a framework.
It's something that a task runner.
Exemple: You use SASS, you want something that compile all your sass file in CSS file. You create a task and webpack have a task now. And you can ask him to automaticaly compile the file when change.

Maybe what you want it's more have two project:

- One who handle the data an may available with an api
- One who is the web ui for the user who get the data and format it in a beautifull UI

Webpack won't be your solution. Continue with your VueJS and look at VueX for your data handling browser side.

Comment: hi, sorry for the unclead title, I understand that VueJS is a framework and want to use Wepack in order to accelerate  the development process but not sure where to start. I just can find guide for node.js apps development with webpack